# How do I get an Object from the Primary Key

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, linq

In C# and Sqllite I am using this to retrieve an object from it's primary key (the object property `Id` is marked `[PrimaryKey]`)

```
return Connection.Table<MyObj>().Where(o => o.Id.Equals(idToFind)).First();
```

Seems a bit verbose. Is there an easier way to retrieve the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?view=netframework-4.8) method:

```
Connection.Table<MyObj>().Find(idToFind);
```